# Table Header Using Jquery - Cell Border Colour?

Tags: jquery, css, border

I've managed to get floating headers working on my table and it seems to be fine, except the floating header is missing the cell borders that are normally visible when not floating.

The example **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7WcRZ/)** shows what's happening.

I'm assuming I'll need to apply some css styling, so I've tried :

```
border: '1px solid red'
```

but that didn't do anything..

Any ideas ?

**UPDATE**

Using the following stops the horizontal scrolling. any way to stop the extra space vertically, but still allow horizontal scrolling ?

If you want to sort out the massive space at the bottom, you can add the following css:

```
> #table_container { position:relative; overflow:hidden; } 
>
> with the following jQuery
> 
> $("#table_container").height($("#main_table").outerHeight());
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated your Fiddle to show the fix. What I did was remove the body of the clone and keep it visible. The `visibility: hidden` was causing the borders to mysteriously vanish.

Here's the updated code: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7WcRZ/7/)